# How to prove that the equation $x^{2n}-2x^{2n-1}-\cdots-2nx+(2n+1)=0$ have no real roots?

Tags: calculus

I came up with this:

Substitute with $y=\dfrac{1}{x}$, then $(2n+1)y^{2n}-2ny^{2n-1}-\cdots-2y+1=0$. Try to prove that the function $f(y)=y^{2n+1}-y^{2n}+y^{2n-1}+\cdots-y^2+y$ is increasing.

I tried to plot the graph of $f(y)$ and it looks like a monotonous increasing function, but how to prove it?

Comment: Can you please write some more terms in $x^{2n}-2x^{2n-1}-\cdots-2nx+(2n+1)=0$?

Comment: @Mason Your 2nd & 3rd term are negative in question, which is different in your above comment.!

Comment: emmmm. It's a problem from my textbook, and I just copy-and-pasted it from my book. And I agree with @Mason

Comment: 2nd & 3rd term means for $j=1,2$

Comment: @Empty I guess that's a typo in either the problem or the transcription thereof.

Comment: @闫嘉琦 In case I am right about the typo, $f(y)$ is the sum of a geometric progression. Write it in the closed form and take the derivative, then you should be able to prove it's positive.

Comment: @Mason `My equation matches the title` Not quite: $x^{2n}-2x^{2n-1}\color{red}-\ldots-2nx+(2n+1)=0$. That $\,\color{red}-\,$ should be a $\,\color{red}+\,$ instead, and that's where I suspect the typo is.

Comment: I have it in a closed form. But I am not sure how taking the derivative helps us out. Do you want me to post the closed form?

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying your function

$$P(y)=\sum_{j=0}^{2n} (j+1)(-y)^j$$

by $(y+1)^2$ gives

$$P_2(y)=(2n+1)y^{2n+2}+(2n+2)y^{2n+1}+1.$$

Its derivative is

$$(2n+1)(2n+2)\left(y^{2n+1}+y^{2n}\right)=(2n+1)(2n+2)y^{2n}(y+1).$$

Can you see why this means that $P_2(y)\geq 0$ for all real $y$, with its minimum reached at $y=-1$ (the new root we have added and can check in $P$ instead of $P_2$ later)?